# How can I send a Sharepoint List item ID to an Excel file?

Tags: sharepoint, excel

I have a Sharepoint (2007) list with some items in it. When I click on one of these items, it will open an Excel (2003) file with a lot of macros. I need to get the ID of this (Sharepoint) item and send it to a cell of my Excel file... Then a macro will be executed and get all the data we need for this ID.

How can I send the item's ID to my Excel file ?

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I once write a DataTable into an new excel file. So you can go ahead and change the function parameter from DataTable to SPList/SPLisItem, and write to an existing file (my current implementation writes to a new Excel file everytime, I execute this function). Also, make sure you add references for the Excel (COM) objects for e.g. Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library etc. If you need more help let me know.

```
  public void excelgenerate(DataSet ds)
  {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oAppln;
        //declaring work book
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oWorkBook;
        //declaring worksheet
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oWorkSheet;
        oAppln = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oWorkBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)(oAppln.Workbooks.Add(true));
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range wRange;
        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            oWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)(oWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing));
            oWorkSheet.Name = table.TableName;
            oWorkSheet.Activate();
            DataRow dr = table.Rows[0];                
            string path = dr["Path"].ToString();
            if (path.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] mylist = path.Split('\\');
                var features = Array.FindLastIndex(mylist, str => str.Equals("Features"));
                string stringmine = "Type ---> " + mylist[4]
                   + "/" + mylist[5]
                   + "     Project Name ---> " + mylist[6]
                   + "     Feature Name ---> " + mylist[features + 1];
                oWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = stringmine;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range colrange = oWorkSheet.get_Range(oWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1], oWorkSheet.Cells[1, 8]);
                colrange.Merge(true);

            }


            int ColumnIndex = 0;

            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                ColumnIndex++;
                oWorkSheet.Cells[2, ColumnIndex] = col.ColumnName;
                wRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)oWorkSheet.Cells[2, ColumnIndex];
                wRange.Font.Bold = true;
            }
            int rowIndex = 1;
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                rowIndex++;
                ColumnIndex = 0;
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    ColumnIndex++;
                    oWorkSheet.Cells[rowIndex + 1, ColumnIndex] = row[col.ColumnName].ToString();
                }
            }
            oWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
            oWorkSheet.Rows.AutoFit();

        }         

        string fileName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + ".xls";
        Console.WriteLine("Number of sheets written : " + oWorkBook.Worksheets.Count);
        oWorkBook.SaveAs(fileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, null, null, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false, null, null, null);
        oWorkBook.Close(null, null, null);
        oAppln.Quit();

    }
```

For executing the Macro using C# ASP.NET and SharePoint, I would recommend you using this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683)

Hope it will answer your question!

Comment: Doing office automation (Office.Interop.Excel) from ASP.NET will get you into lots of trouble - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 - but I am not -1'ing this as it would be a useful code sample for a client side app.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there a reason why you cannot link the SharePoint list data directly into a worksheet and bring your macros into that spreadsheet I think the steps below will get you what you need. It seems too simple...there must be a reason this does not work for what you're trying to do. In any case, here are the steps to make this work:

1) Make sure the SharePoint list actually has an indexed column that enforces unique values. You can check this by looking at the document library settings. Look to make sure there is an index column under the columns listing. If there is not one, you can create one by selecting the "create new column" action, select your data type and make sure that you select the radio button that says "enforce unique values".

2) Export the library to excel using the "export to excel" options in the library's main page menu. This will establish a data link by default and store an excel query file at a default location on your machine that you can discover by going to the data tab and selecting "connections".

3) Copy the macro into the spreadsheet that is linked to your data source and adjust the references in your macro to extract the information you need from the SharePoint list.

Hope this helps.